# How to tell Protractor not to stop at the failure of a single block (Given. When. Then) or scenario, but to continue performing all the other features

Tags: selenium, protractor, cucumber, report

I'm using Protractor, Selenium webdriver with Cucumber and chai expectations for my project. I want to tell protractor not to stop at the failure of a single block (Given, When, Then) or scenario, but to continue to perform the tests and mark all those who go wrong in console and in my reports (cucumber-reports).
How can Protractor do that? Thank you for your help.

Here my protractor.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const jsonReports = process.cwd() + "/reports/json";
const Reporter = require("../support/reporter");

exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
  //getPageTimeout: 60000,
  //allScriptsTimeout: 500000,
  capabilities: {
    browserName: process.env.TEST_BROWSER_NAME || "chrome",
    'chromeOptions': {
     //'args': ['--user-data-dir=~/.e2e-chrome-profile'],
      'args': ['--disable-web-security', '--user-data-dir=~/.e2e-chrome-profile']
    }
  },
  framework: "custom",
  frameworkPath: require.resolve("protractor-cucumber-framework"),
  specs: ["../features/login/*.feature", "../features/second/*.feature", "../features/pageDetails/*.feature", "../features/header/*.feature"],
  // resultJsonOutputFile: "./reports/json/protractor_report.json",
  onPrepare: function() {
    var chai = require('chai');
    chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
    chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
    chai.should();
    global.expect = chai.expect;
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
    require('babel-register');
    Reporter.createDirectory(jsonReports);
  },
  cucumberOpts: {
    strict: true,
    format: 'json:./reports/json/cucumber_report.json',
    require: ["../stepDefinitions/login/*.js", "../stepDefinitions/second/*.js", "../stepDefinitions/pageDetails/*.js", "../stepDefinitions/header/*.js", "../support/*.js"],
    //tags: "(@Login1 or @Login2 or @Login3 or @Login4 or @Login5 or @Login6 or @Login7 or @Second1 or @Second2 or @Second3 or @PageDetails1 or @PageDetails2 or @PageDetails3 or @PageDetails4 or @Header1 or @Header2 or @Header3 or @Header4)"
  },
  onComplete: function () {
    Reporter.createHTMLReport();
  }
};
```

Comment: That's protractor's default behavior (just tried it in a local project). It might be an added plugin that is causing this. Take a look at (or share) your `protractor.conf` file

Comment: @MMansour Hi! Thank you for your answer. I edited my question with the protractor.config.js file. I hope it helps to understand the problem.

Comment: I haven't used cucumber before so I am purely guessing here. Maybe try changing strict to false. I found this [link](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/509e64fd5d9835c9101b33a642e6ccac459025b8/features/strict_mode.feature) maybe it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing happened :(

Comment: add `ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true` into `export.config` in protractor.conf,get detail from here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

Comment: Thank you @yong. it worked partly, but not completely. Let me explain: If there is an error in "When", at the moment it skip the rest of the feature file. I would only skip the block that went wrong and that did everything else. Whether they are of the same feature file or are related to others, I want everything to continue

Comment: @yong I've double checked and it's not good either. The step is ignored, but eventually the error is not reported between the logs. Only one F appears to indicate that something has failed, skipping others block "when/then" in the file. I need that cucumber behave normally in case of an error, so that it is signaled well, but don't block the "When, Then" blocks of the same feature to go directly to the next feature. I want at the end of the execution of the test, I'm returned all the errors in the app and not that to find out the other errors I must first fix the previous error every time

Comment: No one can help me? :/

Comment: Protractor with jasmine framework it is the default behaviour to continue. I think the fact you are using a custom framework (protractor-cucumber-framework) the solution needs to be found there.